# Where I can get a tablet with Ubuntu, or I could use Ubuntu on any tablet that meets requirement?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I'm just wondering Does Ubuntu sell the tablets or can I buy one with the right requirements and put Ubuntu on to it as the new operating system??

Comment: Please, ask one question per question,

Answer (score 4):

At present Ubuntu Touch is not sold with any tablets, but Canonical provides flashable images for use on specific devices. You can flash Ubuntu Touch onto the Nexus 7 and 10, or you may be able to compile it for other devices. Please look at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices for the list.

The short summary - for now, the officially supported device images available from Canonical are the Galaxy Nexus and Nexus 4 phones, and Nexus 7 and 10 tablets, but you'll have to flash it yourself, after backing up your data and unlocking/rooting your device. Other devices are more or less supported by the community.